# writing upload multiple files at a time functionality in dot net (C# particularly)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, file-upload

I want to write "upload multiple files at a time" functionality during upload files in dot net.Any help will be highly appreciated.I am not allowed to use JQuery.All i want is core dotnet.

Comment: You need to provide a bit more detail, have you tried it yourself already? If so post what you've done.

Comment: I need to provide functionality to user wherein he can browse to a folder from the desktop and select multiple files just like windows explorer.I can't use any Active-x control,java or flash.After selection, I can upload the files to a database using HttpFileCollection.But my main concern is how to provide multiple file selection functionality in .net 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply can't be done in HTML4. But in HTML5 you can use

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html#input.file.attrs.multiple